# Index template aliases is not assigning properly for indices?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index templates in the below format:

```
GET _template
        {
  "data_mar": {
    "order": 0,
    "template": "data-2017-03-*",
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "1"
      }
    },
    "mappings": {

    },
    "aliases": {
      "mar_month": {

      }
    }
  },
  "data_feb": {
    "order": 0,
    "template": "data-2017-02-*",
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "1"
      }
    },
    "mappings": {

    },
    "aliases": {
      "feb_month": {

      }
    }
  },
  "data_jan": {
    "order": 0,
    "template": "data-2017-01-*",
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "1"
      }
    },
    "mappings": {

    },
    "aliases": {
      "jan_month": {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I created indices like this data-2017-01-25,data-2017-02-25,data-2017-01-25. In such a way each index will go to one alias as per i specified above.But instead it is created like this:

```
{
  "data-2017-01-25": {
    "aliases": {
      "jan_month": {

      }
    }
  },
  "data-2017-02-25": {
    "aliases": {
      "feb_month": {

      },
      "jan_month": {

      }
    }
  },
  "data-2017-03-25": {
    "aliases": {
      "jan_month": {

      },
      "mar_month": {

      }
    }
  }
```

}

Since i know that index template cant create dynamic aliases based on year & Month . I am using this approach..

May i know why this is happening like that?

THANKS

Comment: There is a typo error in your march month index pattern definition. Template pattern for march month should be `data-2017-03-*` .

Comment: Can you update your question with results of following command `GET /_template` . I suspect you might have defined your jan month index template with pattern something like `data-2017-*`

Comment: Templates look good. I've tried to create indices with same patterns you provided and they are working as expected.

Comment: you are saying it is working fine..In plugin you had tried? I tried in kopf

Comment: I used simple REST API.

Comment: Thanks.. I think the problem is with kopf plugin when i tried in Sense it worked fine..